# How to move fields from profile page to a new page

Tags: users

By default, there are some settings that are on the edit profile page in drupal. e.g. contact settings. Others appear e.g. private message and share content settings as modules (private message and user relationship) are installed.

1. Is it possible to move all these to a new page with its own path (www.example.com/settings) and menu (named settings)?
2. Can this be done with Views? If yes, can the concerned field on the profile page be hidden?

Thanks in anticipation.